# Unexpected output in javascript while using arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does this array get 7 copies of data?

```
$('body').on('click', '#BtnSaveMed', function() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  var Prescription = DBrand = DGeneric = DDose = DDoseUnits = DFreq = DDurn = DDurUnits = [];
  var loop = 0;
  $(".DrugRow").each(function() {
    console.log("Looped:" + loop++);
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    id = id.replace("DrugRow", "");
    console.log("id:" + id);
    BrandVal = $("#brand" + id).val();
    GenericVal = $("#generic" + id).val();
    DoseVal = $("#dose" + id).val();
    DoseunitVal = $("#doseunits" + id).val();
    FreqVal = $("#freq" + id).val();
    DurnVal = $("#durn" + id).val();
    DurnunitVal = $("#durnunit" + id).val();
    console.log("Brand:" + BrandVal + " Generic" + GenericVal);
    count = 0;
    if ( (BrandVal != "") && (GenericVal != "")) {
      console.log("if loop count:" + count++);
      DBrand.push(BrandVal);
      DGeneric.push(GenericVal);
      DDose.push(DoseVal);
      DDoseUnits.push(DoseunitVal);
      DFreq.push(FreqVal);
      DDurn.push(DurnVal);
      DDurUnits.push(DurnunitVal);
    }

  });
  var jsondata=JSON.stringify(DBrand);
  console.log("DBrand is " + jsondata);
  Prescription = [DBrand, DGeneric, DDose, DDoseUnits, DFreq, DDurn, DDurUnits];
  var jsondata=JSON.stringify(Prescription);
  console.log(jsondata);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <span for="" class="text-left">Brand Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <span for="">Generic name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <span for="">Dose</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <span for="">Units</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5">
       <span class="text-nowrap" for="">Frequency</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
       <span for="">Durn</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <span for="inputEmail4">Units</span>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row DrugRow" id="DrugRow1">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="text" id="brand1" class="form-control BrandName input-sm ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Brand name" aria-label="BrandName" aria-describedby="" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
       <input type="text" id="generic1" class="form-control GenericName input-sm" placeholder="Generic name" aria-label="GenericName" aria-describedby="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <input type="text" id="dose1" class="form-control Dose input-sm" placeholder="Dose" aria-label="Dose" aria-describedby="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <input type="text" id="doseunits1" class="form-control DoseUnits input-sm" placeholder="mg" aria-label="DoseUnits" aria-describedby="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <input type="text" id="freq1" class="form-control Frequency input-sm" placeholder="OD" aria-label="Frequency" aria-describedby="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <input type="text" id="durn1" class="form-control Durn input-sm" placeholder="5" aria-label="Durn" aria-describedby="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
       <input type="text" id="durnunit1" class="form-control DurationUnits input-sm" placeholder="days" aria-label="DurationUnits" aria-describedby="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
       <a id="DelRow1" class="btn btn-danger btn-large DelRow" href="#" tabindex="5"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-23"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
       <a id="AddRow2" class="btn btn-primary btn-large AddRow" href="#" tabindex="5"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Console output:

```
Clicked
Looped:0
id:1
Brand:AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET GenericAMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG
if loop count:0
DBrand is ["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""]
[["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""]]
```

Expected data in Prescription:

```
["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""]
```

Data in Prescription:

```
[["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""],["AUGMENTIN DUO 375MG TABLET","AMOXICILLIN 250MG+CLAVULANIC 125MG","","","","",""]]
```

Why does my array have seven copies of what I was expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var Prescription = DBrand = DGeneric = DDose = DDoseUnits = DFreq = DDurn = DDurUnits = [];
The above array type variables are reference type. That's why there is duplicate record. 
You can change the way of defining the variable like below:
var Prescription = []; var DBrand =[]; var DGeneric =[];
Var DDose = []; var DDoseUnits = []; var DFreq =[]; var DDurn =[]; var DDurUnits = [];